# Поиск нужных данных в массиве из структур на Си и возможность многопоточности в Си

Tags: c, массивы, многопоточность, структуры

Собственно изучая разные структуры данных, одно из последних это хеш таблицы. Построены на бинарных деревьях, разных списков. Где хэш функция делит данные, грубо говоря на 10 потоков, дописывая цепочки коллизиями. И у меня возникла идея =)
В моем проекте 1.500.000 русских слов в массиве структур.

```
struct MyWords{
  int hash;
  char len;
  char word[36];
}
```

Естественно поиск по хеш коду занимает не определенное время.
Но появилась идея, еще без реализации в коде, искать следующим образом.
Поиск одновременно с 4 позиций.

```
1)с начала (0-375000).
2)с с середины(750.000-375001) к началу.
3)с середины к концу (750001-1.125.000)
4) с конца к середине (1.500.000-1.250.001)
```

Теоретически данные будут найдены быстрее чем даже деление хеш функцией на 10 цепочек (Hash % 10).
А если эти функции поиска включить в разные потоки (видел на С++ примеры многопоточности, на Си пока не встречал).Так же пишут что если запустить 4 потока, пока они все не закончат, продолжения не будет! Тогда ОБЛОМ :(
Изучая strtok написано что из-за многопоточности используйте strtok_s и strtok_r. Значит некая автоматическая многопоточность используется, нужно КАК-ТО ПОДСТРОИТЬ механизм ;)
Хотелось бы реализовать, хотя бы без потоков. Но как вызвать одновременно 4 функции? =)
В общем нужны идеи по реализации такого алгоритма.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150256/discussion-on-question-by-francnet--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Стоит описать реальную задачу, а не только свое видение реализации

Comment: @MBo Хорошо. У вас есть 1500000 рус. слов в ASCII. Записанных в файле как выше указанная структура. Всё это загружается в память. Получается массив на 1.5кк структур. Вы вводите текст и программа проверяет на ошибки ваши слова. Вообще куча вариантов реализации словаря ;) От обучения AI до примитивного Т9+ ;) И вот такой метод никто не применял, поиск в 4 направлениях.